# pydantic v1 vs v2: dict field inside a model

Tags: python, pydantic

In pydantic V1, if i have a class with a dict attribute, and i pass a model into it, it will be converted to a dict:

```
class Test(pydantic.BaseModel):
    x: dict
class X(pydantic.BaseModel):
    name: str

x = X(name="name")
test = Test(x=x)    

Test(x={'name': 'name'})
```

But in pydantic V2, if i will do the same, i will get a validation error, saying it expects a dict and not a model.

Is there anyway to reserve such a behavior? or the only option is that i convert the model to a dict by myself?

Answer (score 0):

I find this behavior a bit surprising as well, because Pydantic usually does type coercion. And `dict(model)` just works fine. However looking at the [type coercion table in docs](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/conversion_table/), it seems the behavior has been changed to only allow to coerce from `Mapping` and `dict` types.

In principle you can restore the behavior with a reasonable amount of code, like so:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, BeforeValidator
from typing import Annotated

AsDict = Annotated[dict, BeforeValidator(lambda v: dict(v))]

class Test(BaseModel):
    x: AsDict

class X(BaseModel):
    name: str

x = X(name="name")
test = Test(x=x)

print(test)    
print(Test(x={'name': 'name'}))
```

Which prints

```
x={'name': 'name'}
x={'name': 'name'}
```

But I think one should keep in mind, that the behavior has probably been changed for good reasons. So if you can work with a different solution (why not make `x` an `X` type?), this would probably be preferable.

I hope this helps!